# cannot trap python exception from imported module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a script to take temperature from one-wire sensors and put the temperature into redis. The script takes the list of one-wire devices from a file called alias1.py which contains pairs of friendly names and one-wire bus sensor addresses and takes the temperature from each one in turn. However if the sensor is unavailable I want to catch the exception and step over it. At the moment this just sets it to 6 degrees but I may change the action later. Unfortunately I am having difficulty with this and can't see a direct parallel in other cases.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import logging
from onewire import Onewire
import redis
from alias1 import sensors

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
room_float = {}
room_integer = {}
rooms ={}
ow = Onewire("%s:%d" % ("localhost", 4304))
for key in sensors:
    roomID = sensors[key]
    s = ow.sensor(roomID)
    try:
            temperature = s.read("temperature")
            logging.info("found device %s (type = %s)" % (s.path,s.sensor_type))
    except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError, AttributeError):
            temperature = bytes([54])
            logging.info("device or attribute not found %s")
    rooms[key] = temperature
    float_temp = float(temperature)
    int_temp = int(float_temp)
    r_server = redis.Redis('localhost')
    r_server.hset(key, "temp_now", int_temp)
```

Once the for statement reaches the missing sensor, the script hangs indefinitely and only by hitting control c can you see the issue. BTW I have put quite a few exceptions statements in there in desperation :)

```
File "./one-wire-redis-write2.py", line 17, in <module>
temperature = s.read("temperature")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/onewire/__init__.py", line 85, in read
    return self.__getattr__(attr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/onewire/__init__.py", line 80, in __getattr__
    if attr not in self.attrs:

< Above line 80 repeated ad nauseum >

    if attr not in self.attrs:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/onewire/__init__.py", line 107, in attrs
    self._attrs = self._ow.get(self.path).split(',')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/onewire/__init__.py", line 33, in get
    return _ow.get(str(os.path.join(self._path, *path)))
KeyboardInterrupt
```

looking at line 80 of the underlying onewire module [https://github.com/kipe/python-onewire/blob/master/onewire/**init**.py](https://github.com/kipe/python-onewire/blob/master/onewire/__init__.py)

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr not in self.attrs:
            raise AttributeError('Attribute "%s" not found in %s.' % (attr, self.__str__()))
        return self._ow.get(self.path, attr)
```

It seems that an AtrributeError is raised but I can't catch it. The sensor will not have an attribute "temperature" as the sensor address is wrong so doesn't exist so should raise the exception Any ideas how I can see this error and use it in an except or similar construct?

Comment: The `raise AttributeError` is never reached, as the `self.attrs` property appears to cause an infinite recursion spiral. I can't figure out from the fragment of traceback where the loop is however.

Comment: Here's from the command line split over 3 comments Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
>>> from onewire import Onewire
>>> ow = Onewire("%s:%d" % ("localhost", 4304))
>>> s = ow.sensor("28.02CA27060000")
>>> temperature = s.read("temperature")
>>> s = ow.sensor("28.12CA27060000")
>>> temperature = s.read("temperature")

Comment: ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/onewire/__init__.py", line 85, in read
    return self.__getattr__(attr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/onewire/__init__.py", line 80, in __getattr__
    if attr not in self.attrs:

Comment: Seems like you need to debug `onewire` (even though you didn't write it).

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/onewire/__init__.py", line 80, in __getattr__
       if attr not in self.attrs:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/onewire/__init__.py", line 107, in attrs
    self._attrs = self._ow.get(self.path).split(',')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/onewire/__init__.py", line 33, in get
    return _ow.get(str(os.path.join(self._path, *path)))
KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: Seems that way, I can use onewire shell commands and I can catch exceptions but its well ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that something in the `attrs` property is causing an `AttributeError` to be raised.  (Please don't confuse this with the `AttributeError` raised on line 81: as far as I can tell that line never gets reached.)

Because the class `Sensor` has a `__getattr__` method, this is called whenever any attempt to access an attribute of a `Sensor` instance fails with an `AttributeError`.  When an attempt to read the property `self.attrs` raises an `AttributeError`, Python interprets this as there being no attribute with the name `attrs`.  So it calls `__getattr__` to find the value of the `attrs` attribute.  But, of course, `__getattr__` contains an attempt to read `self.attrs`, so the whole thing goes around again and again until the stack overflows.

One way to debug it is to replace the `attrs` property in `onewire/__init__.py` with the following.  It catches an `AttributeError`, displays its traceback and raises a different exception.  The different exception stops Python from going to `__getattr__` to find the attribute value.  You'll need to import the `sys` and `traceback` modules:

```
    @property
    def attrs(self):
        try:
            if self._attrs:
                return self._attrs
            self._attrs = self._ow.get(self.path).split(',')
            return self._attrs

        except AttributeError as e:
            print("AttributeError in attrs property:")
            traceback.print_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])
            print("AttributeError: %s" % str(e))
            print("=" * 80)
            raise ValueError("AttributeError in attrs property: %s" % str(e))
```

In Python 3 you can in fact make do without the three calls to `print` and the call to `traceback.print_tb` (and the `sys` and `traceback` imports): Python 3 detects that an exception is being thrown within an `except` block and will print both tracebacks.

Another way is to catch `AttributeError` in `Onewire.get()` (lines 32-33 of `onewire/__init__.py`) and raise a different exception.

Comment: Thanks Luke!,Success, it continued on to the next sensor after hitting the exception. I'm rather new to python, I shall have a go at submitting this as a bug on github unless you would like to? The following comments is the output now.

Comment: heating@hc1:~/ow$ ./one-wire-redis-write2.py
INFO:root:found device 28.BBE826060000 (type = DS18B20)
INFO:root:found device 28.438128060000 (type = DS18B20)
AttributeError in attrs property:
INFO:root:device or attribute not foundr %s
INFO:root:found device 28.CBBA28060000 (type = DS18B20)
INFO:root:found device 28.9DAF28060000 (type = DS18B20)
INFO:root:found device 28.8C8D27060000 (type = DS18B20)
INFO:root:found device 28.B67E27060000 (type = DS18B20)
heating@hc1:~/ow$

Comment: @FarmerGiles: If you want to submit this to the GitHub issue tracker for this project, feel free to.  If you do, please include a link back to this question.

Comment: Will do Luke, again many thanks for the help, saved me days of head scratching :)